# BroadcastOn function not work in laravel event broadcast?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher

**I used pusher for my project. I configure broadcasting as per laravel docs. When I fired my event pusher does not work for me. But when I send data from pusher console then pusher receive this data. I also try vinkla/pusher. Its work fine but laravel event broadcasting not work. It's not broadcast my messages. Please help me.**

**Here is my Event**

```
 <?php
        
        namespace App\Events;
        
        use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
        use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
        use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
        use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
        use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
        use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
        use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
        
        class ChatNotification implements  ShouldBroadcast
        {
            use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;
        
            public $message;
            /**
             * Create a new event instance.
             *
             * @return void
             */
        
            public function __construct($message)
            {
             $this->message=$message;
        
            }
        
            /**
             * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
             *
             * @return Channel|array
             */
            public function broadcastOn()
            {
                dd($this->message);
                $GroupId=$this->message->fk_group_id;
                if(!empty($GroupId) && !is_null($GroupId)){
        
                    return new PresenceChannel('Room.'.$GroupId);
                }else{
                    return new PrivateChannel('Chat.'.$this->message->to_id);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you changed your broadcast driver in the .env file to be pusher?
Have you run composer require pusher/pusher-php-server?
Have you compiled your Javascript dependencies with npm run dev?
Have you added your credentials and cluster to the .env file?
Have you uncommented the following line in config/App.php?`App\Providers\BroadcastServiceProvider`

Comment: Thank u so much sir for reply. I have done all these requirements but still not working.

Comment: When my event fire, my values pass in the __construct but BroadcastOn function did not run.